# Adding background transparency and custom ordering in legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggnewscale

Let say I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

data = 
structure(list(grp1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"
), grp2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"), val = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6)), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

col_define = c('red', 'orange', 'blue', 'lightblue')
names(col_define) = c('A', 'B', 'C', 'D')

ggplot(data, aes(x = grp1, group = grp2, y = val)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_define, breaks = c("A", "B"), name = "1") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_define, breaks = c("C", "D"), name = "2") +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction = 'vertical', 
        legend.box.margin = margin(), 
        legend.box.background = element_rect(fill = alpha('#e5e5e5', 0.60), size = 0.1, linetype = 'solid', color = '#333333'))
```

As we can seen I tried to add background transparency in my plot using `element_rect(fill = alpha('#e5e5e5', 0.60)`, however is not working. Is there any alternate way to add transparency in the background for this plot?

I also want to change the order in *label of legend* like `2, 1`, instead `1, 2`. Basically I want to apply some custom ordering in case there are many levels.

Any pointer will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Legend backgrounds are always a bit tricky. As we have to deal with multiple elements. Also I'm not 100% sure what you mean by add background transparency. But the first thing I did was to remove the color and the fill for the `legend.background`, i.e. the box drawn around each legend (whereas `legend.box.background` is the background of the box drawn around all legends (; BTW: There is also the background of the single legend keys which is set via `legend.key`. :D ).

The easy part is the ordering of the legends which could be set via the `order` argument of `guide_legend`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggnewscale)

data <-
  structure(list(grp1 = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y"), grp2 = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"), val = c(
    1,
    2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 5, 6
  )), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")

col_define <- c("red", "orange", "blue", "lightblue")
names(col_define) <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")

ggplot(data, aes(x = grp1, group = grp2, y = val)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_define, breaks = c("A", "B"), name = "1", guide = guide_legend(order = 2)) +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_define, breaks = c("C", "D"), name = "2", guide = guide_legend(order = 1)) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "top",
    legend.direction = "vertical",
    legend.box.margin = margin(),
    legend.background = element_rect(color = NA, fill = NA),
    legend.box.background = element_rect(
      fill = alpha('#e5e5e5', .6), size = 0.1, linetype = "solid", color = "#333333"
    )
  )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = grp1, group = grp2, y = val)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_define, breaks = c("B", "A"), name = "1") +
  new_scale_fill() +
  geom_col(aes(fill = grp2)) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = col_define, breaks = c("C", "D"), name = "2") +
  theme(legend.position="top", legend.direction = 'vertical',
        legend.background = element_rect(fill="gray",
                                         size=1, linetype="solid", 
                                         color ="gray"))
```

[image]